# Backbone view structure: how to nest a view in a layout and delegate events

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

i'm new on backbone, and i need to create a view structure like this.

```
<header>
  <nav>...</nav>
</header>
<section id="content">
  here i want to dynamically render a sub-view with its own events..
</section>
<footer>...</footer>
```

the sub-view changes when the user click on a link on the navigation, and its always a different sub-view (the HomeView with the news or the LoginView for the authentication process, for example...)

How can i achieve this, without delegating all the events on the LayoutView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Backbone.Router`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router). Instead of handling the navigation link click events in a view, match their `href` properties up with routes.

So if you have a navigation setup like this:

```
<nav>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#login">Login</a>
</nav>
```

Your router would look something like this:

```
Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    home:   'homePage',
    login:  'loginPage'
  },
  home: function() {
      $("#content").html(new HomeView().render().el);
  },
  login: function() {
      $("#content").html(new LoginView().render().el);
  }
});
```

Comment: Your code works, but if i want to bind an event on a button of the LoginView? put an events: {'click #button': 'action'} on my LoginView dont seems to work...

Comment: @cl0udw4lk3r I think that sounds like an unrelated problem. Maybe the events are not getting delegated correctly?